# In a metric space with a countable base, how does every open cover have a countable subcover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a mertic space, and let $\left\{ V_{\alpha} \right\}$ be a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that, for every $x \in X$ and for every open set $G \subset X$ with $x\in G$, there is some $V_\alpha$ such that
$$x \in V_\alpha \subset G.$$

Then the collection $\left\{ V_\alpha \right\}$ is said to be a base for $X$.

Now suppose $X$ has a countable base $\left\{ V_1, V_2, V_3, \ldots \right\}$, and let $\left\{O_\beta \right\}$ be an open cover of $X$; that is, let $\left\{O_\beta \right\}$ be some collection of open sets such that
$$ X \subset \bigcup_{\beta} O_\beta. $$

Then how to show that some countable subcollection of $\left\{ O_\beta \right\}$ also covers $X$?

Of course, every element $x \in X$ is in some $O_\beta$, which in turn is a union of some subcollection of the countable collection $\left\{V_1, V_2, V_3, \ldots \right\}$.

What next? How to obtain a countable subcollection of $\{O_\beta\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given metric space $X$, countable base $\{V_n\}_1^{\infty}$, open cover $\mathcal{O} = \{ O_i \}_{i \in I}$.

First, construct a countable subset of I. Define a function $f: S \rightarrow I$, where $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ are the indices of base elements which are entirely contained in some element of open cover $\mathcal{O}$. Define $f(n) \rightarrow i_n$, where $V_n \subset O_{i_n}$. Now the image of S under f is an at most countable subset of I: $f(S) \subset I$.

Second, we show $X \subset \cup_{k \in f(S)} O_k$. Let $x \in X$. Then $ x \in O$ for some $O \in \mathcal{O}$ (defn of cover). Then $x \in V_n \subset O$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (defn of base). Then $n \in S$, and so $x \in V_n \subset O_{f(n)}$. $\square$

Answer (score 4):

well you need the axiom of choice. since $\{V_\alpha\}$ is countable, and is a basis, for every $V_i$ choose $O_i \in  \{O_{\beta}\}$ satisfying $V_i \subset O_i$. we may write $O_i = \psi(V_i)$

every $x \in X$ is covered by at least one member of $\{O_{\beta}\}$. since this is open it must contain some $V_x$ with $x \in V_x$. now take the corresponding $O_x = \psi(V_x)$

the collection $\{O_x\}_{x \in X}$ is countable and covers $X$

Comment: You don’t actually need the full strength of the axiom of choice; the result is actually equivalent to $CC(\Bbb R)$, the axiom of countable choice for subsets of $\Bbb R$, which says that if $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R$, then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}S_n\ne\varnothing$. More important, it’s not true that every member of the base is contained in some member of the open cover. For each $i$ let $\mathcal{O}_i=\{O\in\mathcal{O}:V_i\subseteq O\}$, and then choose one member of each **non-empty** $\mathscr{O}_i$.

Comment: thank you Brian. i was hoping someone might clarify what weaker assumption would suffice. and thank you also for picking up on the empty set loose end in my argument. i did have a feeling of unease, but being still somewhat of a tyro, i ignored it and blundered on

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: David Holden, how do we know that for every $V_i$, there does exist a \textit{single} $O_\beta$ that covers this $V_i$?

Comment: good point. Brian spotted my error concerning that unjustified assumption and has given the correct treatment in his comment above.

Comment: David Holden, Yes, he has, but I'm unable even to comprehend his argument. What if no $V_i$ could be covered by a single $O_\beta$? Or what if some could be so covered, while others could not?

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is to prove that every second countable space is [Lindelof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) (in more common notation).

So, let's prove $\text{Second Countable}\implies\text{Lindelof}$.

Let $X$ be second countable with countable basis $\mathscr{B}$, and let $\Omega=\left\{U_\alpha\right\}_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$ be an open cover for $X$. By assumption, for each $\alpha\in\mathcal{A}$ we can cover $U_\alpha$ with some collection $\mathscr{B}_\alpha$ of elements of $\mathscr{B}$. Note then that $\displaystyle \Sigma=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}\mathscr{B}_\alpha$ is a countable open cover for $X$. So, for each element $O$ of $\Sigma$ choose an element $U$ of $\Omega$ containing it (by the axiom of choice) and define the function $f: \Sigma\rightarrow\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$ by $f(O) = U$. Then, $\Gamma = f(\Sigma)$ is an open cover of $X$ (since its union contains the union over all the elements of $\Sigma$ which is $X$) and is countable since $f$ is a surjection and $\Sigma$ is countable. Thus, $\Gamma$ is our desired countable subcover of $\Omega$.

Comment: Paul, thank you for your answer, but are you sure you haven't made a mistake with the symbols and notation you've used? I'm afraid I'm not being able to fully make sense of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots\}$ be a countable open base of $M$, and let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $M$. For each $n$, choose a set from $\mathcal{U}$ that contains $V_n$, call it $U_{i_n}$. If for some $n$ we cannot find a set from $\mathcal{U}$ that contains $V_n$ then so be it. Then, we will have some list:

$$V_1\subseteq U_{i_1}, \quad V_2\subseteq U_{i_2}, \quad V_3\subseteq X, \quad V_4\subseteq U_{i_4}, \quad \ldots$$

where $V_n\subseteq X$ represents the inability to find a set from $\mathcal{U}$ that contains $V_n$. Let $N\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be the set of all $n$ for which $U_{i_n}$ exists.

We propose that the collection $\{U_{i_n}\}_{n\in N}$ is a countable subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. That it is countable is obvious, so we just need to show that $M\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in N} U_{i_n}$. Let $x\in M$ be given, then because $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $M$, $x\in U_i$ for some $i\in I$. Moreover, since $U_i$ is open, it can be written as some union of $V_n$'s, i.e, $x\in V_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It must be that $n\in N$, otherwise, there is no set from $\mathcal{U}$ that contains $V_n$, this is a contradiction because $V_n\subseteq U_i$. Since $n\in N$, $U_{i_n}$ exists, therefore, $x\in V_n\subseteq U_{i_n}$, so $x\in \bigcup_{n\in N} U_{i_n}$ as desired. $\Box$

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot for the answer. I also want to add that $N$ is non-empty. This is because for any $x\in X$, there exists $i\in I$ such that $x\in U_i$. Since {$V_1,V_2,...$} is a base, there is a $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $x\in V_k\subset U_i$. That is, $k\in N$.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly inspired from [David Holden](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/967465/427810)'s answer. I have mainly just organised it a bit more.

Also, by countable, I shall mean finite or countably infinite.

---

Let $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \cal A}$ be the open cover that you had mentioned.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ define
\begin{equation*} 
\mathcal{O}_n = \{O_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathcal{A}, V_n \subset O_\alpha\}.
\end{equation*}
(That is, the collection of all those elements of the original cover which contain $V_n$.)
Note that $\mathcal{O}_n$ need not be nonempty for every $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ (So far, we don't even claim that $\mathcal{O}_n$ is nonempty for any $n$ but our arguments later will show that it is. (Assuming $X \neq \varnothing$, of course.))

Let $N = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \mathcal{O}_n \neq \emptyset\}.$
For any $n \in N,$ $\mathcal{O}_n$ is nonempty and thus, we can choose an element $U_n$ from it. (This is essentially using (some sort of) the axiom of choice.)

Observe that each $U_n$ is an element of $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}.$ (That is, each $U_n = O_{\alpha_n}$ for some $\alpha_n \in \mathcal{A}.$)

Consider the countable subcover (it is a subcover by the above observation) given by
\begin{equation*} 
    \{U_n\}_{n \in N}.
  \end{equation*}
That this is countable is clear. We now show that it is a cover. (Note that we haven't claimed so far that $N \neq \emptyset.$)

Let $x \in X.$ We show that $x \in U_n$ for some $n \in N.$
Since $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ is a cover of $X,$ there exists $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in O_{\alpha}.$

Since $\{V_n\}$ is a base, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in V_n \subset O_\alpha.$
Clearly, $n \in N$ (since $O_\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_n$).  Moreover, $U_n \in \mathcal{O}_n$ and thus, $V_n \subset U_n.$

Since $x \in V_n,$ we see that $x \in U_n$ and hence, we see that $\{U_n\}_{n\in N}$ is a cover, as desired.